# MVC 4 Routing Listing page and Detail page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having to do a 'hack-around' getting simple routing to work as I need.

```
site.com/Event   <--- controller = Event, action = Index

site.com/Event/{id}   <--- controller = Event, action = Details

site.com/About   <--- using default router settings
```

Current code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Event",   // Route name
     url: "Event",    // URL with parameters
     defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults

 );

routes.MapRoute(
     name: "EventID", // Route name
     url:  "Event/{id}", // URL with parameters
     defaults:  new { controller = "Event", action = "Details", 
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults

);

routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                     id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Is there a better way to write the Event and Event/{id} .. ?

**UPDATE - WORKING CODE**

```
{
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "WebDefaultApi",// renamed WebDefaultApi to avoing unique name conflict in API DefaultApi
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Details",
    "{controller}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Event", action = "Details" },
    new { id = @"^\d+$" }
);


routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
}
```

Comment: Is `{id}` always numeric or follow some type of pattern?

Comment: Is there a reason replacing "Event" in the `url` with `{controller}` in both routes doesn't work? Am I missing something?

Comment: I replaced it with {controller}.. not working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the Id required and an integer. Also, since this is more specific, have it be first.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Details",
                "{controller}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Event", action = "Details" },
                new { id = @"^\d+$" }
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

Also, if you only want this route to apply to specific controller, you can limit:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Details",
                "{controller}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Event", action = "Details" },
                new { id = @"^\d+$", controller= @"(event|news|resources)" }
            );
```

Comment: Shouldn't the default action be "Details"?

Comment: I dont see the 'Details' action ?

Comment: Why do you have **{controller}/{action}/{id}** when my example has **{controller}/{id}** ?

Comment: Because you wanted to "have Event, News, Resources, and more pages, each with detail page (News/{id}, etc .. )". This will accommodate that requirement

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta  you have `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"` but I did not want to have the `action` in the url .. just the controller and id.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta - please see my working code above. If you correct your code (removing the 'key' from each) your code does work. But 'as it is' it does not work. The error: "..routing Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified.."